# serializes ajax calls without interrupting by failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I need to make a list of ajax calls execute sequentially. In other words,
one starts after another finishes.

I implement this by chaining jQuery promise. And I need the calls executed no matter the former ones succeeded or not. So I wrap the promise returned by jquery to a new one. It works. But I wonder if promise could support this case directly without using the wrap.

```
function getOne(apple) {
    return $.get(apple)
    .done(function() {
        console.info("I'm done " + apple);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.info("I fail " + apple);
    });
};

function getAll(apples) {
    return _.reduce(apples, function(result, apple) {
        return result.then(function() {
            var d = $.Deferred();
            getOne(apple).always(function() {
                d.resolve();
            });
            return d.promise();
        })
    }, $.when(1));
};
```

Comment: Do you have to use "promise" ? have you tried recursion?

Comment: No. I did try and found promise leads to less codes. But the 4 level indents reduce that benefit. So this question comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this pseudo code helps:

```
var sequence = Promise.resolve();
for(loop){
   sequence = sequence.then(function(url){ 
      return ajaxGet(url);
   }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
   })
}
```

the idea is that you chain promises one after another, and the next one starts only when previous resolves or rejects.

Comment: Thanks.It seems the problem could be easily solved with Standard Promises implementation.